# Infinite dimensional manifolds in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, mathematical-physics, differential-geometry, spacetime-dimensions

In GR the concept of a manifold is very useful. However, all of these manifolds are of finite dimension. Is it possible to define a manifold with [infinite dimension](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/infinite-dimensional+manifold) (ie much like Hilbert space in QM) such that we can still define terms such as curvature, tensor fields and other such concepts that appear in GR on this manifold?

If such a manifold exists does it have physical applications?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows insufficient prior research. A simple google search answers most of this question. See e.g. [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/infinite-dimensional+manifold). If you still have a question after looking around some more, please do return to ask it :)

Comment: Manifolds in GR aren't just finite-dimensional, they're 4-dimensional. Sure you can go from 4 to $\infty$, but why would you? In QM you can easily construct physical scenarios for any finite dimensionality of the Hilbert space, so it's no surprise to make the leap to $\infty$. But our universe is simply 4-dimensional, and any other dimensionality you come up with is pure differential geometry, not GR.

Comment: I think it would be useful to distinguish between infinite but countable dimensions as opposed to infinite continuous dimensional (like the difference between a Fourier series and a Fourier transform).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks two different questions: 1) Is it possible to define e.g. curvature on an infinite dimensional manifold (this should probably be in Math.SE anyway), 2) Are infinite dimensional manifolds relevant to any physical systems?

Please separate into two posts.

Comment: @ChrisWhite GR can described in any integer dimension. Why do you specifically say it's only d=4?

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, manifolds are by definition topological spaces, which resemble locally an inner-product space. Since there are vector spaces (with a dot product) of infinite dimension, then there shall be infinately-dimensional manifolds as well. The infinity of the dimension is not a problem for the tensors as well - each multi-linear function over a vector space can be called a tensor... The same holds for the connection, the curvature, the holonomy, and others - the only downside is that we are no more able to write them via a finite set of coefficients.

(PS Furthermore, any topological space that locally resembles some space A can be called a "manifold of type A" - e.g. Hilbert manifolds, Banach manifolds, etc. So definitely, the answer to your question is affirmative.)

Regarding whether those generalised manifolds are applicable in physics - I guess so, but unfortunately I cannot give you any examples.

Comment: One thing I can think of is that the configuration space and phase space of a hamiltonian system in GR (and not just in GR) is technically an infinite-dimensional manifold. This is mentioned in Wald's book, as well as a poisson-bracket is given in one of the footnotes, but this setting is not developed there in any rigour.